# Getting a dictionary of objects fetched from a dictionary of urls with rxjs/typescript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an object such as

```
let UrlObject = { 
  'url1' : './someurl1.json',
  'url2' : './someurl2.json',..
};
```

I would like to fetch all urls with rxjs and let the subscriber know only after all has been fetched. Also, I would also like the subscriber to get a result object with the original keys. i.e.

```
let result = { 
  'url1' : fetchedObject1,
  'url2' : fetchedObject2,..
}
```

The best I got is:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatAll'; 
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

let observableBatch = [];
for (let k in urlObject) {
    observableBatch.push(
      this.http.get(templats[k]).map(
         (res) => {
             return Observable.of({[k] : res.json()})
         }
      )
    )
}
let mergedObs =Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).concatAll();
mergedObs.subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

But i get an error of " Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}[]'."

How can i fix this error?
Is there a shorter more elegant way to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `forkJoin` you don't need to use `concatAll`. `forkJoin` subscribes to all source Observables and waits until all of them complete. In other words `forkJoin` emits just values, not Observables.

Anyway, if you don't want to create an array of Observable beforehand or if the source of URLs is not fixed you could do for example this:

```
let UrlObject = {
    'url1' : './someurl1.json',
    'url2' : './someurl2.json',
    'url3' : './someurl3.json',
    'url4' : './someurl4.json',
    'url5' : './someurl5.json',
};

function httpRequest(key, url) {
    return Observable.of(url)
        .delay(1000)
        .map(response => [key, response.split('').reverse().join('')]);
}

Observable.from(Object.keys(UrlObject).map(key => [key, UrlObject[key]]))
    .flatMap(arr => httpRequest(arr[0], arr[1]))
    .toArray()
    .map(arr => {
        const obj = {};
        arr.forEach(respArr => obj[respArr[0]] = respArr[1]);
        return obj;
    })
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints to console:

```
{ url1: 'nosj.1lruemos/.',
  url2: 'nosj.2lruemos/.',
  url3: 'nosj.3lruemos/.',
  url4: 'nosj.4lruemos/.',
  url5: 'nosj.5lruemos/.' }
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/hozumix/2/edit?js,console

Comment: I would like to use angular http module. In your example you attached the key to the http content by creating an Observable that contained both. How can attach the key to the Observable i get from http.get()?

Comment: It's the same just instead of `httpRequest()` use `http.get()`

Comment: http.get() does not have the additional parameter you use to pass the key (arr[0] in your code)

Comment: Then use `httpRequest()` and just instead of `Observable.of(url)` use `http.get()`